# Why link errors (Undefined symbols) in my Mac app for references that already built and linked successfully in the static library?

Tags: c++, macos, cocoa, clang, linker-errors

My app uses a library that I also have the source for and build successfully.  The library uses some source code, from zxing to be clear, and again, it finds and resolves all function calls just fine.  But when I use the library, I'm getting some linker errors (Undefined symbols) referring to those zxing references.  Doesn't seem possible since the app can't know anything about that code -- it's buried in the library.  How to resolve these errors?

From Xcode:

```
Ld DerivedData2/ailhost/Build/Products/Release/ailhost.app/Contents/MacOS/ailhost normal x86_64
    cd /Users/me1/Documents/ailhost_mac/svn/trunk/ailhost
    export MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.10
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++ -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.sdk -L/Users/me1/Documents/ailhost_mac/svn/trunk/ailhost/DerivedData2/ailhost/Build/Products/Release -L/Users/me1/Documents/ailhost_mac/svn/trunk/ailhost/ailhost -F/Users/me1/Documents/ailhost_mac/svn/trunk/ailhost/DerivedData2/ailhost/Build/Products/Release -filelist /Users/me1/Documents/ailhost_mac/svn/trunk/ailhost/DerivedData2/ailhost/Build/Intermediates/ailhost.build/Release/ailhost.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/ailhost.LinkFileList -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/../Frameworks -mmacosx-version-min=10.10 -stdlib=libstdc++ -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -lboost_system-mt -lboost_thread-mt -lSLABHIDtoUART -framework Accelerate -lProcessor -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/me1/Documents/ailhost_mac/svn/trunk/ailhost/DerivedData2/ailhost/Build/Intermediates/ailhost.build/Release/ailhost.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/ailhost_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/me1/Documents/ailhost_mac/svn/trunk/ailhost/DerivedData2/ailhost/Build/Products/Release/ailhost.app/Contents/MacOS/ailhost

Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "zxing::DecodeHints::DecodeHints()", referenced from:
      Processor::processQRCodeInternal(int, int, int, int) in libProcessor.a(Processor.o)
  "zxing::BinaryBitmap::BinaryBitmap(zxing::Ref<zxing::Binarizer>)", referenced from:
      Processor::processQRCodeInternal(int, int, int, int) in libProcessor.a(Processor.o)
  "zxing::HybridBinarizer::HybridBinarizer(zxing::Ref<zxing::LuminanceSource>)", referenced from:
      Processor::processQRCodeInternal(int, int, int, int) in libProcessor.a(Processor.o)
  "zxing::GreyscaleLuminanceSource::GreyscaleLuminanceSource(zxing::ArrayRef<char>, int, int, int, int, int, int)", referenced from:
      Processor::processQRCodeInternal(int, int, int, int) in libProcessor.a(Processor.o)
  "zxing::Result::getResultPoints()", referenced from:
      Processor::processQRCodeInternal(int, int, int, int) in libProcessor.a(Processor.o)
  "zxing::Result::getText()", referenced from:
      Processor::processQRCodeInternal(int, int, int, int) in libProcessor.a(Processor.o)
  "zxing::qrcode::QRCodeReader::QRCodeReader()", referenced from:
      Processor::processQRCodeInternal(int, int, int, int) in libProcessor.a(Processor.o)
  "zxing::Exception::deleteMessage()", referenced from:
      zxing::Exception::~Exception() in libProcessor.a(Processor.o)
  "zxing::Exception::copy(char const*)", referenced from:
      zxing::Exception::Exception(zxing::Exception const&) in libProcessor.a(Processor.o)
  "zxing::String::getText() const", referenced from:
      Processor::processQRCodeInternal(int, int, int, int) in libProcessor.a(Processor.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: Speaking as someone who has never even heard of zxing, take this with a grain of salt. I'd expect a `-lzxing` or similar in the linker command line. The library name could be something goofy, but I don't see anything zxing-ish. Boost, a UART-something, and Processor, but no zxing

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear enough.  The zxing references are all in the library (look for libProcessor.a) and they all compile, resolve and link perfectly.  The output I provided however, is from the app that uses the library, in which there are no zxing references anywhere, in the code or project, which is exactly why the linker errors make no sense. There are no refs to them anywhere that the app could know.

Comment: It's worth taking a look at libProcessor.a to make sure your zxing xcode really is in there. Here's a tool that should help: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/nm.1.html

Comment: I'll check this out.  But I don't see how the library itself could successfully get past its link phase unless the zxing functions are present.  Stay tuned.  If you're right you can enter an answer and I'll mark it correct.

Comment: Yes, they're in libProcessor.a all right.

Comment: Well, that eliminates the usual suspects. Is the zxing code built with a different makefile that may have options incompatible with the rest of your code? Can't see that surviving the linkage with libProcessor.a, either.

Comment: Not a different "makefile".  Both are 2 different Xcode projects.  It's kind of bizarre actually.  None of the other code is the library throws link errors.  The library has a folder titled "zxing".  I added it to the project in the normal way.  Am able to call its classes within the library's source. Nothing fancy.  Know any way to get verbose commentary on the link process in Xcode?

Comment: ... breaking news: Just went to Build Phases in the library's project. Not a single trace of the zxing code (!) yet all the other necessary source files are listed there.

Comment: I added the zxing folder with its source to "Compile Sources" under "Build Phases" but it had no effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed.  The problem was that the files down in the zxing folder were not being compiled into the library bc neither the folder ("zxing") nor any of the files were part of the target. I verified this by scrutinizing "Compile Sources" under "Build Settings".  (Maddening that it will show you no compile errors when you build a static library when the files actually are *not* built into the resulting binary.)  For the benefit of my gentle readers, how this happened is when I right-clicked on my main project folder in Xcode and selected "Add files to ..." and then browsed and chose the folder having the needed source ("zxing") I used the settings as they were, "Create folder references" being selected. I removed the folder then re-added anew, but the second time chose "Create Groups" (see attached pic).  Voila!  The files got added to the target as needed.  The static library then built without probs (as before) only when I actually had my app link to the library I got no Undefined symbols errors.

[image]